# How to create a while loop with delay in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have this pseudo code:

```
var STATUS = '';
while (STATUS !== "SUCCEEDED") {
    STATUS = getStatus();
    anotherFunc();
    delay(3s);
}
```

The goal of this code is to keep calling an api to check a status of something, the api returns IN_PROGRESS or SUCCEEDED. So I want the while loop to keep calling `getStatus()` to get the value of STATUS and break the loop when it is SUCCEEDED. I also want to put a delay between each iteration.

This can't be done easily with Nodejs. So please help me out.

Comment: Restructure using a promise and `setTimeout()`-based retries?

Answer (score 2):

you don't even need a while loop for that, simply use `setInterval()` and within the callback check if your condition is satisfied to clear the created interval.

```
var STATUS = '',
    idx = setInterval(function() {
        STATUS = getStatus();
        if (STATUS === "SUCCEEDED") { // I guess you wanted a check for STATUS instead of VAR
            return clearInterval(idx);
        }
        anotherFunc();
    }, 3000); // the interval when to call the function again 3000ms = 3sek
```

Comment: for some reason this code only runs once when I test

Comment: this would implicate that the `getStatus()` function returned `"SUCCEEDED"` after the second time. You can fake `getStatus` and see when no "SUCCEEDED" is ever returned the setInterval callback will be called consequently

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to continually do something on a delay.  It accepts a function which you can use to do the api call, but before you do the call you should check if the last call was successful.

Once a call is successful you can clear the interval.

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args